# Syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input, though I think it has right end number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is unexpected end, expecting end-of-input.But I think the end number which the file has is the right one.

Ruby version :ruby 2.6.3p62

```rb
class Car
attr_accessor :type, :capacity, :speed,:seater,:defect

    def initialize(type, capacity,speed=150,seater,defect=false)
        @type = type
        @capacity = capacity
        @speed = speed
                @seater= seater
        @defect= defect
    end

   def speed_with_seater

         if seater<=capacity
             speed = speed*0.95**seater
         else
             puts "passengers exceeds the capacity."
             end
   end

   def defect_with_speed

          if defect=true
                speed = speed*0.6
          else
            puts "there is no defect"
          end
    end


end
```

car.rb:35:syntax error, unexpected end, expecting end-of-input

Comment: ProTip: format your code properly, using a tool. Syntax errors like mismatching ends are so much easier to spot then.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code:

1. You should define all optional arguments at the end of the list of arguments:

   ```rb
   def initialize(type, capacity, seater, speed=150, defect=false)
   ```
2. Instead of `if defect=true` it should be `if defect == true`

Comment: `if defect=true`  is a logical error, not syntactical. But the other one is spot-on.

Comment: Another logical error is that all setters are missing `self.`. That will be their next question, "why my setters don't work and values remain nil"